# JSON Model - don't add all objects in array if using method "arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

Here's my JSON data

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name":"Soup",
    "price":200,
    "isOK":1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name":"Salad",
    "price":100,
    "isOK":0
}]
```

I have created JSONModel as follows

```
@interface ProductModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float price;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isOK;
@end
```

Next,

```
NSArray* modelsArray = [ProductModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:objects];
```

Now what I want is

```
if(isOK)
{
   // then add the model into the modelsArray
} else {
   // then don't add the model into the modelsArray
}
```

Is it possible to write this logic somewhere within the model file, without iterating the modelsArray and then removing the objects one by one on the basis of isOK ?

Comment: are want remove object from modelsArray on the baces of isok value?

Comment: @balkaran singh thats correct, but without iterating the array again

Comment: you can use NSPredicate for this.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Haider did you get array in modelsArray

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['isOK'] CONTAINS '1'"];
NSArray* filted_Array_OK = [modelarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@",filted_Array_OK);

NSArray* filted_Array_NOT_OK = [modelarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF['isOK'] CONTAINS '0'"]];
NSLog(@"%@",filted_Array_NOT_OK);
```

Here modelArray contains your all values **isOK** = 0 and **isOK** = 1

with this code you got 2 different array that contains 2 type value that are **isOK** = 1 and **isOK** = 0 now you can use directly array when you want to use .

Output :
**filted_Array_OK**

```
 (
        {
        id = 1;
        isOK = 1;
        name = Soup;
        price = 200;
    },
        {
        id = 3;
        isOK = 1;
        name = peace;
        price = 900;
    }
)
```

**filted_Array_NOT_OK**

```
(
        {
        id = 2;
        isOK = 0;
        name = cake;
        price = 200;
    },
        {
        id = 4;
        isOK = 0;
        name = bread;
        price = 800;
    }
)
```

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if there could be a function in the model file, which would return true or false and would decide whether the object will be added in the array or not. Anyways thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Haider i just give you 2 array so when ever you want use it you can easily access it .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use NSPredicate though;

```
   NSArray* modelsArray = [ProductModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:objects];    
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.isOK == %@ && SELF.isOK != nil", @YES];
   NSArray* filtedArray = [modelsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* modelsArray = [ProductModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:objects];    
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isOK == 1"];
NSArray* filtedArray = [modelsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if there could be a function in the model file, which would return true or false and would decide whether the object will be added in the array or not. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Using Fast enumeration you can do this .

```
for (ProductModel* productModel in objects) {
  if(productModel.isOK){
   [modelarray addOjbect:productModel];
  }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do ?